# django 'no such table' one more time

Tags: django-models

Till few days ago i had only 2 models in my app, but now i decided to add one more model to 'models.py'. 'Makemigrations' app_name displays no errors but 'migrate' shows:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: app_name_et
```

What i did was deleting 'migrations' folder, adding 'django.contrib.sessions' to 'installed apps' in settings.py, running migrate with options as below:

```
python ../../manage.py makemigrations app-name
python ../../manage.py migrate --fake
python ../../manage.py migrate --fake app_name
python ../../manage.py migrate --fake app_name zero
```

Dunno what else could i do to create table. I can't delete db because there is allready data that belongs to earliest models.

```
python ../../manage.py inspectdb
```

is not showing last table but two created before:

(..)

```
class app_nameDane(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    mac = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    addr_ip_switcha = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    device_on_port = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    dns_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    switch_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    switch_port_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    addr_ip_on_port_poprzednio = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    addr_ip_switcha_poprzednio = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    vlan = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    godzina = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    error = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    addr_ip_on_port = models.CharField(max_length=14, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'net_knf_dane'


class app_nameMaki(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    mak_mac = models.CharField(max_length=7, blank=True, null=True)
    mak_man = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'net_knf_maki'
```

Model, that has problem with table looks as follows:

```
class Et(models.Model):
        e_user = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
        e_dev = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
        e_session = models.CharField(max_length=9, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
        e_start = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
        e_stop = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
        e_summary = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
        e_ip = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
        def __unicode__(self):
          return self.e_user
```

I'm out of ideas. Last 3 days  i was looking for solution everywhere without luck. If you have any idea or maybe i'm missing something please let me know.

regards

Answer (score 0):

I have created this table manually with:

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

(..)